# How to send multiple form data using jquery form object?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created FormData object from a form using jquery as bellow. and sending  it to the controller side to `FormCollection` using ajax.

```
var form = $('#kycFormTab1').get(0);
var data = new FormData(form);
```

I want to send multiple form data to the ajax. How can i achieve it? How to append form data of the other form to 'data' object?

I want to access form data with name because i am using  FormCollection object to the server side. and i am using single FormCollection object for all form.

Comment: First, you cannot combine formData. Second, I suspect you have multiple forms with same ID.

Comment: You cannot combine form data using the `FormData()` constructor. If you want to send data from multiple forms you'll need to `append()` it to the object manually. *However* it sounds like you should think about amending your HTML structure if you need to submit two forms at once.

Comment: i have multiple forms with diffrent ID. @KK

Comment: Use `data: $(form1).serialize() + '&' + $(form2).serialize().` in an ajax call, or if you have file inputs and need to use `FormData`, then you need to `.append()` each name/value pair of the 2nd form to `data` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: But you should never be using `FormCollection` in mvc. Your method should have parameters for the model in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can append as many data object as like by following this approach:

```
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('form1', $('#kycFormTab1').get(0));
formData.append('form2', $('#kycFormTab2').get(0));
```

and so on.

Comment: using this i get `[object HTMLFormElement]` for each form in `FormCollection` How can i able to access formcollection value by name?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serializeArray()` for each form:

```
var form = $('form'); //Getting all forms 
$.each(form, function(i, formC) { 
      var formDates = $(formC).serializeArray();
      $.ajax({
          data: formDates,
          ...
      })
}
```